# How to avoid this facebook error when trying to authenticate in my site?

Tags: facebook, authentication, oauth-2.0, django-socialauth, python-social-auth

I'm trying to integrate facebook login to my site with python-social-auth.

This is my **setting.py** file:

```
# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'blog',
    'social.apps.django_app.default',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'boeldev.urls'

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'boeldev.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': 'boeldev.db',
    }
}



# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'templates').replace('\\','/'),)

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
  'social.backends.google.GoogleOAuth2',
  'social.backends.facebook.FacebookOAuth2',
  'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
)

SOCIAL_AUTH_LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/entries/'
SOCIAL_AUTH_LOGIN_ERROR_URL = '/login-error/'

SOCIAL_AUTH_GOOGLE_OAUTH2_KEY = 'XXXX.apps.googleusercontent.com'
SOCIAL_AUTH_GOOGLE_OAUTH2_SECRET = 'XXXX'

SOCIAL_AUTH_FACEBOOK_KEY = 'XXXX'
SOCIAL_AUTH_FACEBOOK_SECRET = 'XXXX'

SOCIAL_AUTH_PIPELINE = (
    'social.pipeline.social_auth.social_details',
    'social.pipeline.social_auth.social_uid',
    'social.pipeline.social_auth.auth_allowed',
    'social.pipeline.social_auth.social_user',
    'social.pipeline.user.get_username',
    'social.pipeline.mail.mail_validation',
    'social.pipeline.user.create_user',
    'social.pipeline.social_auth.associate_user',
    'social.pipeline.social_auth.load_extra_data',
    'social.pipeline.user.user_details',
    'blog.pipeline.get_profile_picture',
)
```

But I'm getting following error after the login with facebook:

> "Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration.: One or
>   more of the given URLs is not allowed by the App's settings. It must
>   match the Website URL or Canvas URL, or the domain must be a subdomain
>   of one of the App's domains."

This is my facebook configuration:
[image]

I know there are many issues on stackoverflow related to that error message, but any of them solved my problem.

What I'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: First, you have `App Domains` empty, fill it with `127.0.0.1`, if that doesn't work try with `localhost` (and use the same for `Site URL`). Second, `Site URL` doesn't need to be `http://127.0.0.1:8000/entries/`, the value `http://127.0.0.1` is enough. I prefer to set `localhost` on this setting since it resembles a domain.

Comment: thanks omab! and thanks for python-social-auth!

Comment: No problem, let me post my comment as an answer so you can flag it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you have `App Domains` empty, fill it with `127.0.0.1`, if that doesn't work try with `localhost` (and use the same for Site URL). Second, Site URL doesn't need to be `http://127.0.0.1:8000/entries/`, the value `http://127.0.0.1` is enough. I prefer to set `localhost` on this setting since it resembles a domain.